# Angular 2 - *ngFor with conditional class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am using Angular2 and bootstrap for a component. 
I am trying to add a class to my tr-tag if the property "2" of the test from the *ngFor loop is equal to an imported variable named newTest.
But it's not adding the class.

Here's my component:

```
loadTest() {
      this.testService.getTests()
         .then((data) => {
            this.tests = data
         })
   }

ngOnInit() {
      this.loadTest();
   }
```

The table is displayed correctly, but the class isn't there.

The condition definitely is fullfilled, though.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-reflow">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let test of tests" [class.newDevice]="test.2 === this.newTest" [attr.class]="test.1" >
                <th>{{test.1}}</th>
                <th>{{test.2}}</th>
                <th>{{test.3}}</th>
                <th>{{test.4}}</th>
                <th>{{test.5}}</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Am I doing something else wrong? 
I've tried achieving the same with jquery, too:

```
    loadTest() {
          this.testService.getTests()
             .then((data) => {
                this.tests = data
    if (NewTest.length !== undefined) {
                   let index = this.tests.findIndex((e) => { return e.2 === NewTest })
                   let test = this.tests[index].id
                   jQuery(test).addClass("newDevice");
                }
           })
       )
```

Comment: Why you have `[class.newDevice]` and `[attr.class]`? Aren't these two overriding each other?

Comment: AFAIK `attr.class` should be avoided (causes issues in Safari mobile for example). Use `[ngClass]` instead.

Comment: Could you please try this: `[ngClass]="{ 'newDevice': test.2 == newTest }"`?

Comment: @Martin, yes you where right, they indeed are. Actually, [attr.class] should've been [attr.id], as I forgot to change it after testing with jQuery. Now it works.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I've tried using id="test.1" instead of [attr.id]="test.1", but that didn't work.

Comment: Why `attr.id`. I never mentioned `id`. `[ngClass]="test.1"` instead of `[attr.class]="test.1"`

Comment: Because of my answer to Martin. I don't know what went wrong last time I tried binding to id="{{test.1}}, but now all is fine. @Martin, make your comment an answer and I'll accept. Thanks for the other answers as well, always nice to learn something new for a newbe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[class.newDevice]` and `[attr.class]` are overriding each other.